# Yarn not starting up

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

After I set up a 20 node Hadoop cluster on AWS, which to my knowledge is working, when I try to start up yarn with the code:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

I get these errors:

```
resourcemanager running a process (process #). Stop it first
```

and

```
nodemanager running a process (process #). Stop it first
```

for each of the worker nodes.

my `yarn-site.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ec2-52-207-188-72.compute-1.amazonaws.com</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

is there a solution for this?

Comment: The daemons are already running....

Comment: How do you know **YARN is not starting up** ??You can list-out the java processes by using `jps -ml` command add sudo if required. If the yarn services are running, you should see their PID there.

Answer (score 1):

First:
`call stop-all.sh`

for stopping it and you could be sure by using "JPS" command
then start it again:

```
all start-all.sh
```

Type jps (if namenode don't appear type "hadoop namenode" and check error)